# Generating OData client for Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations

Tags: odata, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

We are currently trying to generate a C# OData client from Visual Studio, in order to read data from a Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations tenant.

But the $metadata file is so large that the C# compiler fails with this error!

> CS8103: Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds
>   allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals.

Is there any configuration/workaround to reduce the size of the $metadata file served from `/data/$metadata?

Comment: Check https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/issues/54

Comment: Downloading the metadata file and manually filtering the entities throughout a 250.000+ lines document? That is not a viable solution.